# ¿Cómo funciona las funciones y la lógica dentro de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, typescript, condiciones, booleano

estoy realizando un curso sobre JS y TS y he llegado a un ejercicio en el cual no entiendo su lógica. Primeramente, os dejo el código:

```js
class car {
    brand: string;
    doors: number;
    fuelTank: number;
    isRunning: boolean;
    type: string;

    createdAt: number;

    constructor () {
        this.brand = 'No brand'
        this.doors = 0;
        this.fuelTank = 100;
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.type = 'No type';
        
        this.createdAt = 31212342;
    }

    turnOn () {

        if (this.isRunning) {
            console.log('El coche ya estaba encendido, ahora se ha roto');
            return; //Cuando se encuentra el return, en JS se detiene la ejecución de ese método.
        }

        if (this.fuelTank <= 0) {
            console.log('El coche no tiene gasoil');
            return;
        }

        this.isRunning = true;
        console.log('El coche está arrancado');
        

        
    }

}

let myAudi = new car();

console.log(myAudi);
myAudi.turnOn();
console.log(myAudi);
```

Al llamar a la función turnOn, en mi lógica, primero seleccione el primer if, cuyo valor de this.isRunning, para mí es falso, entonces debería de ejecutar ese if y terminar el método, pero no es así, si va al final de la función y cambia el valor de isRunning.

No llego a entender porque no ejecuta ese primer if.

También tengo otra duda. isRunning = false (el coche esta apagado), pero si en la función escribo if (this.isRunning === false) si ejecuta ese primer if. Pero desde mi lógica, estoy diciendo que el coche esta apagado, y cuando este apagado muestra ese mensaje, por lo que no entiendo el por que (el código está bien, ya que viene directamente del curso).

Muchas gracias de antemano y espero haberme expresado bien, cualquier aclaración la hare encantado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El primer if verifica si `this.isRunning` es `true`, no se agrega `=== true` porque está implícito. Recuerda que el valor booleano se utiliza para indicar si y no, verdadero y falso, 1 y 0, encendido y apagado, existe y no existe.

Tal vez lo podrías entender como una mezcla de “encendido” y “existe”, al final de cuentas ambos valores son 1 para la computadora.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora lo he entendido mejor :)